# how to initialize a org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.Vector?

Tags: java, apache, math, vector, geometry

I'm trying to create a vector object by importing **org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.Vector**. 
Which confuses me is how to make a instance of it. 
I have tried this way: 
Vector v1 = new Vector(1, 2, 3); 
but the ide says  " **'Vector' is abstract, cannot be instantiated**" 
Does anyone know about this class? thanks.

P.S.  the (1, 2, 3) I use may be misleading. What I want is a dynamic vector which I can assign its dimension to it.

Comment: You just need to instantiate a subclass of `Vector` instead of `Vector` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Vector v1 = new Vector3D(1, 2, 3);
```

You need a class that implements Vector.  The javadocs tell you there are three choices: `Vector1D`, `Vector2D`, and `Vector3D`.

Why they created a 1D vector I'll never know.  I usually call those "scalars".

If you need a larger vector, then use `RealVector` and its subclass, `ArrayRealVector`.

Are you incapable of opening the javadocs and researching on your own?  You'll make faster progress if you do a little thinking on your own.

Comment: but if I want a dimension bigger than 3, e.g. 200. what should i do?

Comment: thank you! I will try to spend more time in reading the javadocs. I'm not familiar with the format of those docs now...

Answer (score 0):

This is interface - [Vector](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/Vector.html)

You should use Vector3D instead.
If you are using Eclipse you can click `Vector` and press `Ctrl+T` to see the hierarchy.

Comment: using Vector3D my vector's dimension is restricted to 3. I want a vector that I can assign its dimension when it's created.

Comment: this library supports only 1, 2, 3 dimensions. If you want more dimensions you need to implement your own `NDimVector`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a true mathematical vector with dot-products and such, with more than three elements, it looks like you will have to create your own class which implements the Vector interface.   Use the apache Vector3D class as a model and just extend it from there.

If you are just looking for a relatively simple array of elements use this class instead:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html